# Grouped Barchart using bargraph.CI

Tags: r, bar-chart

How would I use the sciplot library's (bargraph.CI) to make a grouped barchart showing two bars next to each other for example grass cover and weed cover for the different tree types with the following data.

[image: data from excel given as an example]

Answer (score 0):

before to be able to plot your data, you need to reshape them in a longer format. For that, you can use `tidyr`:

```r
library(tidyr)
DF <- df %>% pivot_longer(., -c(plot, tree), names_to = "Type",values_to = "value")

> DF
# A tibble: 12 x 4
    plot tree  Type  value
   <int> <fct> <chr> <dbl>
 1     1 maple grass    56
 2     1 maple weed     20
 3     2 pine  grass    34
 4     2 pine  weed     45
 5     3 maple grass    72
 6     3 maple weed     15
 7     4 maple grass    32
 8     4 maple weed     47
 9     5 pine  grass    59
10     5 pine  weed     23
11     6 pine  grass    87
12     6 pine  weed      8
```

Now you can plot it using `bargraph.CI`:

```r
library(sciplot)
bargraph.CI(x.factor = tree, response = value, group = Type, data = DF, 
            xlab = "Tree", ylab = "% cover",legend = TRUE, x.leg = 1,angle = 45, cex.names = 1.25)
```

[image]

---

**Alternative using ggplot2**

You can alternatively do the same using `ggplot2` that has the advantage to offer a large panel of customization. However, you will have to first compute the mean and standard deviation. You can do that by using `dplyr` package and `group_by` and `summarise` functions:

```r
library(dplyr)
DF %>% group_by(tree, Type) %>% summarise(Mean = mean (value), SE = sd(value))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   tree [2]
  tree  Type   Mean    SE
  <fct> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 maple grass  53.3  20.1
2 maple weed   27.3  17.2
3 pine  grass  60    26.5
4 pine  weed   25.3  18.6
```

You can combine the `dplyr` and `ggplot` to get the plot:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
DF %>% group_by(tree, Type) %>% summarise(Mean = mean (value), SE = sd(value)) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = tree, y = Mean, fill = Type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge())+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Mean-SE, ymax = Mean+SE), position = position_dodge(0.9),  width=.2)
```

[image]

**Data**

```r
plot = 1:6
tree = c("maple","pine","maple","maple","pine","pine")
grass = c(56,34,72,32,59,87)
weed = c(20,45,15,47,23,8)

df = data.frame(plot, tree, grass, weed)
```